# VBA Opening Save Window Despite Events and Alerts Being Off

Tags: excel, vba

All I am trying to do is save one sheet out of the workbook to a new workbook in the same folder.

But every time I run my code, excel interrupts the execution and opens up the Save As window where you have to select the folder and name of the file, which I have never seen before.

Any Ideas on how to circumvent this? I have Events and Alerts off.

Code:

```
Sub Export_Data()

Dim ws As Worksheet, wb As Workbook
Dim name As String
Dim lcol As Double, lrow As Double
Dim path As String

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("EMPLOYEES")

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

path = "C:\Users\PATH\"

Set wb = Workbooks.Add

ws.Copy Before:=wb.Sheets(1)
On Error Resume Next ' Need this because I get a runtime error 1004, though it still saves it regardless
wb.SaveAs Filename:=path & "People_Data" & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=51 '''' Here is where it opens the save as window??????
wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Delete
wb.Close SaveChanges:=True

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: **Why would you ignore the root cause - error 1004**. This line pops up the dialog as you didn't supply a filename -`wb.Close SaveChanges:=True` From Help *Value Action 
True Saves the changes to the workbook. If there is not yet a file name associated with the workbook, then FileName is used. **If FileName is omitted, the user is asked to supply a file name.*** This line errors so does nothing `wb.SaveAs Filename:=path & "People_Data" & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=51`.

Comment: That error pops up on the save as line before the save changes one. The 1004 error pops up if I take out the wb.close line so the on error is necassary

Answer (score 0):

### Save a Worksheet to a New Workbook

- If nothing else, this should shed some light on what's going on. Your feedback is expected.

```vb
Sub SaveWorksheetToNewWorkbook()
    Const ProcName As String = "SaveWorksheetToNewWorkbook"
    Dim Success As Boolean
    On Error GoTo ClearError
 
    Const SOURCE_WORKSHEET_NAME As String = "EMPLOYEES"
    Const DESTINATION_FOLDER_PATH As String = "C:\Test"
    Const DESTINATION_FILE_NAME As String = "People_Data.xlsx"
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Check if the destination path exists.
    
    Dim pSep As String: pSep = Application.PathSeparator
    
    Dim dFolderPath As String: dFolderPath = DESTINATION_FOLDER_PATH
    If Right(dFolderPath, 1) <> pSep Then dFolderPath = dFolderPath & pSep
    
    Dim dFolderName As String: dFolderName = Dir(dFolderPath, vbDirectory)
    If Len(dFolderName) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "The path '" & dFolderPath & "' doesn't exist.", _
            vbExclamation, ProcName
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook
    
    ' Check if the destination workbook, or a workbook with the same name,
    ' is open.
    
    On Error Resume Next
        Set dwb = Workbooks(DESTINATION_FILE_NAME)
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    If Not dwb Is Nothing Then
        If StrComp(dwb.Path & pSep, dFolderPath, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            MsgBox "The destination workbook '" & DESTINATION_FILE_NAME _
                & "' is open." & vbLf & "Close it and try again.", _
                vbExclamation, ProcName
        Else
            MsgBox "A workbook with the same name as the destination file ('" _
                & DESTINATION_FILE_NAME & "') is open." _
                & vbLf & "Close it and try again.", vbExclamation, ProcName
        End If
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Export the worksheet.
    
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = swb.Worksheets(SOURCE_WORKSHEET_NAME)
    
    sws.Copy ' creates a copy as a new single-worksheet workbook
    
    Set dwb = Workbooks(Workbooks.Count)
    
    Dim ErrNumber As Long
    Dim ErrDescription As String
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' overwrite without confirmation
        On Error Resume Next
            dwb.SaveAs dFolderPath & DESTINATION_FILE_NAME
            ErrNumber = Err.Number
            ErrDescription = Err.Description
        On Error GoTo ClearError
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    dwb.Close SaveChanges:=False ' just got saved
    
    If ErrNumber <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "' Run-time error '" & ErrNumber & "':" & vbLf _
            & ErrDescription & vbLf & vbLf _
            & "This error occurred while attempting to save the workbook.", _
            vbCritical, ProcName
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Success = True
    
ProcExit:
    On Error Resume Next
        If Success Then
            MsgBox "Worksheet saved to new workbook.", vbInformation, ProcName
        End If
    On Error GoTo 0
        
    Exit Sub

ClearError:
    MsgBox "' Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf _
        & Err.Description & vbLf & vbLf _
        & "This error occurred quite unexpectedly.", _
        vbCritical, ProcName 
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub
```